# performing JavaScript action on $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .post

Here's my JavaScript code on my "test" page.

```
$('#link_share_input').keyup(function () {
    var link_share_input = $(this).val();
    if (link_share_input != '') {
        $.post('http://' + window.location.hostname + '/assets/scripts/ajax_dashboard_dynamic_preview.php', {
            preview_type: 'link',
            link_share_input: link_share_input
        }, function (data) {
            if (data !== "") {
                $('.link_preview_span').show();
                $('.link_attachment_preview').html('<div class = "center" style = "padding: 10px 0"><img src = "http://www.assets.buddyweb.me/style_images/loading.gif"></div>');
                $('.link_attachment_preview').html(data);
            } else {
                $('.link_preview_span').hide();
            }
        })
    }
})


$('#video_url_input').keyup(function () {
    var video_url_input = $(this).val();
    if (video_url_input != '') {
        $.post('http://' + window.location.hostname + '/assets/scripts/ajax_dashboard_dynamic_preview.php', {
            preview_type: 'video',
            video_url_input: video_url_input
        }, function (data) {
            if (data !== "") {
                $('.link_preview_span').show();
                $('.link_attachment_preview').html('<div class = "center" style = "padding: 10px 0"><img src = "http://www.assets.buddyweb.me/style_images/loading.gif"></div>');
                $('.link_attachment_preview').html(data);
            } else {
                $('.link_preview_span').hide();
            }
        })
    }
})
```

the `#link_share_input` and `#video_url_input` div's comes from a file which is `$.post`ed onto the page. Unless I put the above JavaScript onto the page it is `$.post`ed from it will work.

How can I get this JavaScript to work on the data `$.post`ed from a file to the "test" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$('#link_share_input').keyup` to..

`$(document).on('keyup', '#link_share_input', function(e) { ... });`

This basically drops an event listener on document, and whenever the keyup event is fired and the target matches `#link_share_input` it will then fire your event callback.  Because you're modifying the HTML over $.post and such it works exactly like you would expect.

Quick note:  This requires jQuery 1.7 and above.  There are other, equivalent methods for older versions of jQuery, `.delegate` and `.live`.